# Permissão negada no Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic, firebase

Estou desenvolvendo um app com o **ionic 3** e o **Firebase** ... Nas regras do *Realtime Database*, que surge o problema: Tento colocar as regras pro tipo "usuario", mas surge o seguinte erro :

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: PERMISSION_DENIED:
>   Permission denied
>
> ERROR Error: permission_denied at /pedidos: Client doesn't have
>   permission to access the desired data.

Estrutura das regras :

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Onde está /pedidos no banco de dados?

Comment: {
  "pedidos" : {
    "-LMmARYYMaRcdeMmDpJm" : {
      "name" : "ASDASD",
      "tel" : "23"
    },
    "-LMnVV3SyodnsDKuKtJO" : {
      "name" : "asdasd",
      "tel" : "23"
    },
    "-LMnW4KKrrUOjaoF1I3p" : {
      "name" : "asdasd",
      "tel" : "231"
    },
    "-LMqiTIhAr-VUMKpq8FD" : {
      "name" : "asdasdsa",
      "tel" : "213"
    },
    "-LMqjg75Q0aJGR_3dHXg" : {
      "name" : "asdsad",
      "tel" : "123"
    }
  }
}

Comment: Então está na raiz, assim como users? (Poste dados relevantes formatados na pergunta)

Comment: Como deveria ser a estrutura correta para o meu banco ? Eu preciso que apenas o usuário possa ler e escrever os seus pedidos. Seria dessa forma ?? :
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
     "pedidos": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
      }
  }
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Penso que as regras da base de dados do **Firebase** estão definidas como `read / write` = `false`, por isso não consegues desenvolver. Para corrigir isso, basta aceder as regras na **Consola do Firebase > Realtime Database** e altera as definições para `true`.

Mais informações [aqui](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/)

Comment: Mas dessa forma, todos os usuários terão acesso a todos as informações ? Eu preciso que determinado usuário, tenha acesso apenas de seus respectivos pedidos, no caso

Comment: De fato isso torna a informação pública. Certifique-se de proteger a base de dados novamente antes de entrar em produção.

Answer (score 0):

De um comentário:

> *Eu preciso que apenas o usuário possa ler e escrever os seus pedidos.*

Primeiro, podemos tentar organizar dessa forma, veja se isto corresponde às suas necessidades:

```
- users
   - uid
      - pedidos
         - idPeDIDoLE7NyOSXaLSZ
            - name: "ASDF"
            - tel: "23"
         - idPeDIDoYWchTgdMk9W1
            - name: "FDSA"
            - tel: "94"
```

Regras:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        //".read" : "$uid === auth.uid",
        "pedidos": {
          ".read" : "$uid === auth.uid",
          ".write" : "$uid === auth.uid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### *Ou* dessa forma

```
- users
   - uid
    //- Informações do usário aqui, nome, email etc.
- uid
   - pedidos
      - idPeDIDoLE7NyOSXaLSZ
         - name: "ASDF"
         - tel: "23"
      - idPeDIDoYWchTgdMk9W1
         - name: "FDSA"
         - tel: "94"
```

Regras:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "$uid": {
      //".read" : "$uid === auth.uid",
      "pedidos": {
        ".read" : "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write" : "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```